# Mootool - Ajax vs $_SESSION PHP

Tags: php, ajax, session, mootools

```
var ajax = new Ajax('process.php', {
   method: 'post',
   data:options,
   onComplete: function(data){
         alert(data);
    }

  });
```

process.php

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['data'] = 'hello';
    echo $_SESSION['data'];
```

index.php

```
  session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['data'];    // return null
```

run ajax i get alert "hello" . Ok
run index.php i don't get anything

i can't get $_SESSION['data'] , it's undefined. why ?

Comment: `process.php` should be quoted: `'process.php'`. And where can't you retrieve `$_SESSION['data']`?

Comment: add quoted, I sure ajax run successfully

Comment: and in which file is your ajax code?

Comment: this looks like a problem with PHP sessions rather than mootools. SID needed? check your php.ini settings, imo. in js you can create fallbacks like `window.sessionStorage.setItem("data", "hello")` -> `window.sessionStorage.getItem("data"); // hello!` (if supported - check if sessionStorage in window to feature detect)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not know the ajax work or no you can do this :
in the process.php take

`file_put_contents('test.txt', 'its work', FILE_APPEND);`

if the test file create it mean you invoke the file
and if its not set the session you must obey as below:

its write on session but if you want to read it you must start session again to read the
session value from the session file on the server again whenever you want read from session

Comment: i have added session_start() and still get undefined

Comment: do you really sure you invoke the process.php ?

Comment: NO need for additional file writing for test. There is an echo in process.php and the echoed text is displayed by alert. So, if correct text is displayed in alert box, the ajax was successful.

Comment: @highelf : yes. i sure , alert box with "hello"

Comment: you need start session after set the value with the ajax

Comment: may be your PHPSESSID is not set

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You may have just left this code out of your example, but your mootools code only creates the Ajax object. To have it send the request, you need to use the request method:

   ajax.request();
2. Are you trying to send the value that you want $_SESSION['data'] equal to in the ajax request? If that's the case, you would look in the $_POST variable to get the values you're sending to the server via the Ajax object (because you've set 'post' as the request method). If you want the values you've sent in the request to be set in $_SESSION you will need to put them there yourself in process.php.

Try out this code (my best idea as to what you're trying to do):

For the javascript/mootools:

```
var ajax = new Ajax('process.php', {
  method: 'post',
  data:{'data':'hello'}
});
ajax.request();
```

In process.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data']; /* $_SESSION['data'] = 'hello'*/
```

Also, if your ajax javascript is contained in the index.php page where you're echoing $_SESSION['data'], then you would need to refresh index.php before you would see the changes to $_SESSION made by your ajax request.